# qemu-kvm Windows won't start

Tags: boot, windows, kvm, qemu

I know that theres similar questions, but this kind of question hasn't only one solution, it depends on the user situation, even if the same message is displayed, so what i've found don't work for me btw

When I start the machine I have the `The Boot Configuration Data for your PC is Missing or contains errors.` message, but I don't know how to repair it

Do you have any lead about that?

---

I found that doesn't work: the OS

> `The Boot Configuration Data for your PC is Missing or contains errors.`

The `kvm` command i'm using to boot what seems to be a Windows VM: `virt-manager`

I did install Windows on that VM: by exporting it from a physical machine

Comment: What have you found that doesn't work? What is the `kvm` command you're using to boot what seems to be a Windows VM? How did you install Windows on that VM? All [in the question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/577373/edit), please.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Unix & Linux StackExchange!

That message seems to come from Windows, so it's not a "missing/wrong type of bootloader" problem.

But apparently the virtual hardware provided by `qemu-kvm` is different enough from the physical machine the VM was exported from, and the exported boot configuration is no longer applicable.

You would need to boot the VM using an ISO image of the appropriate version of Windows installation media, and run its "Repair your computer" function.

Essentially, this is a "how to fix Windows boot?" question for a system that just happens to be a virtual machine. Unfortunately that means this question might be better suited to the [Super User section of StackExchange](https://superuser.com/), unless your question is specifically about the use or configuration of the virtualization layer.